# Trying to create a program which automatically creates an array and populates it with byte values

Tags: java, arrays

I could have a pattern.txt file with the following:

```
45 56

45 56 56 56 e6
```

which only has 2 lines (2 arrays needed).

However, I could have a file with 3 different lines (3 arrays needed).

```
45 56

45 56 56 56 e6

43 e6
```

I need a program that can automatically create an array with the required elements and populate it with each line split with a delimiter (space).

For example,

```
byte[] pattern1= new byte[] { 45, 46 };
byte[] pattern2= new byte[] { 45, 56, 56, e6};
byte[] pattern3= new byte[] { 43, e6 };
```

It also needs converting from hexadecimal to byte for the array.

How would it be possible to do something like this?

I currently have this code which outputs to the console as expected but I need it to be added to  an array.

```
public void loadPattern() {

    loadedPatterns.clear();

    File file = new File(fileName);

    int elements = 0;

    try {
        // Here we use the Scanner class to read file content line-by-line.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // From the above line of code we got a line from the file
            // content. Now we want to split the line with a space as the
            // character delimiter.
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(" ");
            while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                // Get each splitted data from the Scanner object and print
                // the value.
                elements++;

                String part = lineScanner.next();
                System.out.print(part + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class LineMapper {
    // assuming you have this list
    private List<Byte[]> loadedPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    private File patternsFile = new File("pattern.txt");

    public void loadPattern() {
        loadedPatterns.clear();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(patternsFile.toPath())) {
            stream.map(LineMapper::lineToArray).forEach(loadedPatterns::add);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Byte[] lineToArray(String line) {
        return Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")).map(LineMapper::hexToByte).toArray(Byte[]::new);
    }

    private static byte hexToByte(String hex) {
        return (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(0), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(1), 16));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this without the public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException as I just need it as a method once the user clicks "Load Pattern File".

Comment: What is `loadedPatterns`?

Comment: It was just an array I was testing with.

Comment: I will use the arrays to scan for patterns within files after the use has successfully loaded a pattern file.

Comment: @BoredRedBandit it is not an array, arrays don't have `clear()` methods. Is it a List?

Comment: Sorry it is a list.

Comment: I edited my answer, just replace `LineMapper` with your class name in the first and second methods.

Comment: Hi. I get an error saying method lineToArray cannot be declared static on lineToArray(String line)

Comment: You should only copy the methods not the whole class. Copy all lines except for the first and last one.

Comment: Hi. So I changed private File patternsFile = new File("patterns.txt") to private File patternsFile = new File(fileName). With fileName being public String fileName=""; which is changed when the user selects a file within the JFileChooser. but I am getting a AccessDeniedException

Comment: You can test the method with a file without opening a `JFileChooser`. Does it work?